# How to store selected data from database in an array in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server

With this code I'm retrieving the data from the database:

```cs
public static string[] SelectData(string data)
{
    SqlConnection connection = Connection();
    switch (connection.Equals(null))
    {
        case false:
            var cmd = "SELECT command, properties FROM ai WHERE command = @command"
            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(cmd, connection))
            {
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@command", data);
                using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    switch (reader.Read())
                    {
                        case true:
                            connection.Close();
                            return reader["properties"].toString();
                        default:
                            connection.Close();
                            return null;
                    }
                }
            }
        default:
            connection.Close();
            return null;
    }
}
```

How do I store data stored in an database table like this:

property1,property2,property3,property4

In an array like this:

```cs
string[] propertyArray = { "property1", "property2", "property3", "property4" };
```

With invinite possible properties.

Best regards,
Bradley Methorst

Comment: I assume you want to retrieve data from the database, first you need to show us the part of your code that retrieves data, that way we can help you to find out which part needs to be changed

Comment: So the value of `reader["properties"]` is `property1, property2, property3, property4`, and you want to split that into an array? That's poor schema design: **never** put delimited data into a column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Updated answer for your updated question:**

**The simple answer to your question is that you can use [string.Split](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=net-5.0) to separate that string at the commas.** But the fact that you have to do this is indicative of a larger problem with your database schema.

Right now I'm inferring that your table looks something like this:

**ai**

| command | properties |
| --- | --- |
| command1 | property1,property2,property3,property4 |
| command2 | property1,property2 |

You should never put comma delimited values into a database. Try something like this:

**ai**

| command | property |
| --- | --- |
| command1 | property1 |
| command1 | property2 |
| command1 | property3 |
| command1 | property4 |
| command2 | property1 |
| command2 | property2 |

Your query becomes: `SELECT property FROM ai WHERE command = @command`

I would however like to add that even this improved schema is problematic. You don't want to duplicate strings and use them as id's. It's prone to typos and problems when renaming. Instead do something like this:

**command**

| id (int) | name (varchar) |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | command1 |
| 2 | command2 |

**property**

| id (int) | name (varchar) |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | property1 |
| 2 | property2 |
| 3 | property3 |
| 4 | property4 |

**commandproperty**

| commandID (int) | propertyID (int) |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 3 |
| 1 | 4 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 |

Your query roughly becomes: `SELECT command.name as command, property.name as property from commandProperty LEFT JOIN command ON command.id = commandID LEFT JOIN property ON property.id = propertyID WHERE commandID = (SELECT TOP 1 id ROM command WHERE name = @command)`

There might be typos in that query. I haven't actually executed it. Also, it would be best practice to turn these tables into a view that looks like my second example.

**My old answer:**

There seems to be something missing in the question.

Is the problem that the array can not be expanded beyond `property4`? If so try using a `List<string>`.

Is the proplem that you want to associate column values with column names? In that case try using a [`Dictionary<string,object>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2?view=net-5.0) (or `Dictionary<string,T>` where `T` is a datatype common to all the columns).

Alternatively, you can try using C#'s built in [`DataTable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatable?view=net-5.0). I find them to be a bit verbose to use, but they will probably work for your needs.

Comment: basically: ```string[] result = reader["properties"].toString().Split(','); return result;```  right?

Answer (score 1):

I'm editing the answer based on the new information.
I'd still consider using my Dapper wrapper package.

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Cworth.DapperExtensions/#

Create a model class that matches the filed returned in your select.

```
public class MyModel
{
    public string Command { get; set; }
    public string properties { get; set; }
}
```

Use nugget package manager to install package referenced above.
Update your data access class to add using statement;

`using Cworth.DapperExtensions;`

Update your method

```
public async static string[] SelectData(string data)
    {
        var sqlRepo = new SqlRepo(_connectionString);
        var results = await sqlRepo.GetList<MyModel>("MyStoredProc", new { command = data });
        return results.Select(r => r.Properties).ToArray();
    }
```

Note the above assumes you have created a stored procedure in SQL name "MyStoredProc" that that match your select with parameter "command".

Comment: No, it's just 1 row, inside an properties column.